# How to draw a line between two views without using coordinates?

Tags: swift, swiftui, draw

The purpose of my project is to create a view that graphically displays a binary tree. The difficulty is not to use any GeometryReader to set the coordinates to the individual views. These must be arranged with HStack and VStack to avoid overlapping elements or elements placed outside the screen limits.

Here is the function I wrote to try to reach the solution. It's the only one present in the body of the view. If you need to also insert the code I use to create the binary tree.

```
func drawNode(_ node: TreeNode<Int>?) -> some View {
    if let currentNode = node {
        return AnyView(VStack {
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("\(currentNode.value)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            
            HStack(spacing: 12){
                if let leftNode = currentNode.leftChild{
                    drawNode(leftNode)
                    //TODO: Line which connects LeftNode with CurrentNode
                    //Difficulty: it has to be done dynamically using Stacks, otherwise the circles would be get out of the bounds of the screen or will overlap each other
                }
                if let rightNode = currentNode.rightChild{
                    drawNode(rightNode)
                    //TODO: Line which connects RightNode with CurrentNode
                    //Difficulty: it has to be done dynamically using Stacks, otherwise the circles would be get out of the bounds of the screen or will overlap each other
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}
```

I tried to achieve the solution getting the CGRect of the single views after these appeared on the screen, writing something like this code under the view I wanted to get the CGRect:

```swift
.background(
   Geometry Reader { geo in
      Color.clear
         .onAppear{
            frame = geo.frame(in: .global) //frame declared after the first "if" of the function
         }
   }
)
```

Then trying to use the frame I got to draw a Path(). But it seems that frame would be always nil.

Comment: SwiftUI "preferences" can be used to collect positions of subviews. Here's an article I keep returning to when I get stuck: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/15/the-magic-of-view-preferences-in-swiftui/

Comment: As for laying things out, in the current version of SwiftUI, there is a cleaner way for doing custom layouts: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui